# Do I need html tags to do carriage returns?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a problem whereby identical output is being presented differently on an html page.  If I have;

```
Test

Test
```

as an entry in a database table, one part of my page will permit the linespaces (which I want), but another part of my page will not and just cut out the spaces, making them look like

```
Test Test
```

Can someone help me to identify possible issue?

Comment: You need to write the correct HTML and/or CSS to render as desired - it doesn't matter *where* the data comes from or who creates it. Using "BR" is a common approach (that is often suitable), but it is not exclusive.

Comment: By default, HTML will collapse multiple whitespace characters into a single space (or newline when the text needs to wrap). If you need to preserve white-space you'll need to use `<pre>` for preformatted text, or use CSS to style the text as `white-space: pre`.

Comment: If you're curious about all the rules, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425830/definition-of-html-whitespace-rules and related. In any case, I would recommend using a markdown format (that supports a to-HTML transformation), if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure to understand)

You must convert the `\n` in `<br/>` (use function nl2br() if you are in php)

Comment: Thank you, 56ka, this put me on the right track.  I had applied nl2br on one part of the page, but not on the output of the other.  Thank you for the help, all fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do. Unless you've got some CSS and/or `<pre>` tags to force HTML to honor line breaks, they're generally treated as whitespace. To get a "line break" in HTML, you have to use a `<br />` tag.