# Where is the definition of white space in HTML Living Standard?

Tags: html, whitespace

Does the space character in HTML Living Standard mean only ASCII space character?

I know that the HTML4 specification defines whitespace as follows:

> ### 9.1 White space
>
> The document character set includes a wide variety of white space
>   characters. Many of these are typographic elements used in some
>   applications to produce particular visual spacing effects. In HTML,
>   only the following characters are defined as white space characters:
>
> - ASCII space (&#x0020;)
> - ASCII tab (&#x0009;)
> - ASCII form feed (&#x000C;)
> - Zero-width space (&#x200B;)

As a result, HTML4 recognizes that all whitespace characters other than those defined below are treated in the same way as ordinary characters. This fact means that continuous `U+0020` is combined into one, but continuous `U+2009` is not combined into one and maintains a continuous state.

```html
<h2>U+0020 is combined</h2>
<p>this is      loooooooooooo         ng text</p>
<h2>U+2009 (white space that is out of definition) is not combined</h2>
<p>this is       loooooooooooo           ng text</p>
```

I searched the WHATWG Living Standard for a description corresponding to this white space definition in HTML4, but I couldn't find it.
Where is the definition of white space in HTML Living Standard?

I read the following articles, but these did not have the answer to my question.

- [Definition of HTML whitespace rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425830)
- [Why does HTML require that multiple spaces show up as a single space in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433493)
- [How to stop Browser from replacing multiple space by single space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36259826)

Comment: they are many references => HTML character entity references https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: In the second link I found a link to the [css white-space rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#white-space-prop) that might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML Living Standard whitespace is defined as "ASCII Whitespace" referencing the Infra Specification as a dependency. Is it listed as a dependency [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#dependencies), which references [this](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace), defining whitespace as:

```
U+0009 TAB, U+000A LF, U+000C FF, U+000D CR, or U+0020 SPACE.
```